# Regex to remove trailing slash not working

Tags: regex, replace

I am trying to remove the `http://` and trailing slash from a string, so my replace filter looks like this:

`website|replace({ 'http://': '', '/\\/$/': '' })`

The `http://` part works, the trailing slash one doesn't. Why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are getting the twig [replace](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) filter (which does not have the regex capability) instead of the Craft [replace](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) filter (which does).

So this is a bug in Craft, in that their filter is masked by the twig one.

You could use the [trim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html) filter to remove trailing `/`s:

```
website|replace({'http://':''})|trim('/')
```

Or you could use one of Victor's [Twig PCRE Filters](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigPCRE/).

Comment: Thank you Marion! Completely forgot about the `trim` filter - perfect solution :)

Comment: Craft's replace filter overrides Twig's, not visa-versa - although we do keep their base behavior in tact in ours.  I've added an answer for the behavior you were seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Craft's replace filter only supports doing multiple strings replacements at once.  If you want to do a regex replacement, it will have to be it's own separate call.

In your case, you'd have to do something like this:

```
{% set url =  "http://www.google.com/"|replace('http://', '') %}
{{ url|replace('/\\/$/', '') }}
```