# hacksaw plugin - displaying first 100 characters

Tags: plugins, filter

I want to display first 100 characters from a rich text field.

I tried this:

```
{% set sumtext =  entry.bodyContent.type('text').first().text|hacksaw(chars='100', append='...') %}
```

But if there was a new paragraph in the first 100 characters and no full stop - both paragraphs are just joined together without a space.

I then tried:

```
{% set sumtext =  entry.bodyContent.type('text').first().text|hacksaw(allow='<p>', chars='100', append='...') %}
```

But the

gets displayed on the screen instead of the new line.

what is my best method to display the first 100 characters from a rich text field?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the first thing you should do is **remove all HTML tags**. It's not just paragraph tags which could cause you problems... what about `<strong>`, `<a>` or `<img>` tags which get cut off?

For legibility sake, let's also break this down into multiple steps:

```
{% set textBlock = entry.bodyContent.type('text').first() %}
{% set plainText = textBlock.text|striptags %}
{% set sumtext   = plainText|hacksaw(chars='100', append='...') %}
```

And finally, if you **do** want your text wrapped in a paragraph tag, just reapply that when you output it:

```
<p>{{ sumtext }}</p>
```

Since you mentioned having an issue with two paragraphs getting mushed together, let me address that too... You'll want to make use of the [Craft `replace` filter](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#replace), which can handle regex.

Couple of ways you could tackle that:

- `{% set plainText = plainText|replace('/\. */', '. ') %}` (ensures periods are followed by a single space)
- `{% set textBlock = textBlock|replace('/<\/p> *<p>/', ' ') %}` (gracefully combines paragraphs with a space in between)

Comment: Craft's replace filter is masked by Twig's replace filter, and the net result is no regex: [bug report](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285224-bugs/suggestions/7770024-twig-replace-filter-is-masking-craft-replace-filte)

Comment: Ok - so while this bug exists I won't be able to use the 2 reg ex replace options you displayed above?

Comment: [http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9517/130](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9517/130) has some options

Comment: You can also check out the [**Low Regex** filter...](https://github.com/low/low_regex) It's no longer supported, since Craft (normally) has this rolled into the core. But since the core version currently has a bug, you can probably still use Low Regex instead.